# Azure IoTHub ServiceBus to Cloud to Device messages?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Is it possible to add Azure Service Bus to queue Cloud to Device messages? 
When I receive messages I have to be sure that all messages are in the same order that they came to IoTHub. I couldn't find if standard queue in IoTHub provides it. Second reason why I want to use ServiceBus is also longer expiration time, IoTHub provides only 48 hours for message.
I know that I can easily use ServiceBus in DeviceMessages by adding endpoint and route in IoTHub configuration, but what with C2D messages?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it's possible to use Azure Service Bus Queue for communication with C2D messages. But, Azure Service Bus only support AMQP & HTTP protocol for most languages, so it's just suitable for some devices which have better performance, such as RaspberryPi/DragonBoard, etc. But the AMQP or HTTP protocol is too heavy & complex for more little devices like Arduino.

However, Azure IoTHub support MQTT protocol which be so thin & simple & fast for devices, and cost less performance.

Answer for your second question, you can integrate Azure Stream Analytics & Azure Storage services (such as Table Storage/DocumentDB/Data Lake) with IoTHub to store all messages for data persistence. Then, don't worry about the message expiration time, you can retrieve any data which be transmited & stored by Stream Analytics, in anytime & anywhere.

As references, please see the below links to know what & how.

1. [Get started with Azure Stream Analytics to process data from IoT devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-get-started-with-azure-stream-analytics-to-process-data-from-iot-devices)
2. [Build an IoT solution by using Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-build-an-iot-solution-using-stream-analytics)
3. [Stream Analytics outputs: Options for storage, analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs)

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.